# creating an object with static type of base class vs subclass?

Tags: java, object, polymorphism, extend

I cannot figure out the difference between accessing a method of a subclass that is accessed and overwritten using the base class(Object) for the static type of the object versus using the subclass(Point).
For example:

```
public class Point {
int x, y;
...
public boolean equals(Object o){
...
}

public boolean equals(Point p){
...
}
}


Object o = new Object();
Point p = new Point(3,4);
Object op = new Point(3,4);

// here the static type is Point and the dynamic type is point, in this case 
// the equals() method that we choose and gets overwrriten depends on the
// parameter type that is passed. 
p.equals(o);
p.equals(p);
p.equals(op);

// here however the static type is Object so we initially look at the equals() 
// method in our Object class during compile time and check its parameter type   
// which is Object, thus if we overwrite      
// the equals() method we will pick the one that has a type Object parameter. 
// Since the dynamic type of our object is Point, when we are at run time
// we will look for the  equals() method in Point that matches with the   
// method type Object parameter.

op.equals(o);
op.equals(op);
op.equals(p);
```

What i am not seeing is why would i want to use the later rather than the former to specify what method i would like to overwrite? The former depends on the type parameter while the later depends on the type parameter of the static type of our object. I just dont see the benefit of using Basetype obj = new Subclasstype() to access and overwritten method in my subclass. It looks more complicated and the object can only be used to access instances of methods in the subclass that were in the base class, not any other methods in the subclass.

Comment: Note that *overwrite* is not terminology. There is *override* and *overload* which are in turn two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public boolean equals(Point p){
  ...
}
```

The above method has nothing to do with `equals(Object)` except sharing the name `equals`. It does not override it, it cannot be invoked from an `Object`-typed variable, there is no contract for it defined by `Object`.

When you write

```
op.equals(p);
```

you are invoking a method on the `Object` type. The only method called `equals` in that type is `equals(Object)` and this choice is *permanent*. The runtime can only provide a different override of `equals(Object)`, but it will never route the call to `equals(Point)`.

Similarly, when you write

```
p.equals(op);
```

the compiler will again see that you are invoking `equals` with an argument whose static type is `Object`, selecting `equals(Object)`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for clearing that up. I knew that object op could only overwrite the equals() method from the subclass that has an Object type as a parameter but i missed the obvious point that this is exactly why we need to create another object of static type Point to access any other equals() method that is other than an Object type parameter in the subclass Point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are messing up some concepts, so let me explain them:

```
Object op = new Point(3,4);
```

The behavior of variables `o` and `p` are clear, so I'll focus on `op`: it's a variable whose type is `Object`, which means you can use all methods declared in that class. You cannot use `equals(Point p)` method because it does not exist for Object. But, at the same time, the behavior of a method is given by the instance it self, not by the variable which is pointing at it, so `op` is pointing to a Point instance and the `equals(Object)` method has been overwritten, so the behavior of that method is given by the class `Point`.